# using baselineOffset in NSAttributedString problem in iOS 16.4

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

as you can see, after i build project on iOS 16.4 i faced a problem that baselineOffset is not like on iOS 16.0.

what should i do?

[image]

this is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.label.setText("Hello World!")
    }


}


extension UILabel {
    func setText(_ text: String) {
        let attrs = self.generateFontAttr()
        self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attrs)
    }

    private func generateFontAttr() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 120
        paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 120
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        let baselineOffset = 20
        let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font,
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .baselineOffset: baselineOffset
        ]

        return attrs
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution for this issue? Can you confirm that the issue still exists on iOS versions later than 16.4 (16.5.1 for example) ?

Comment: I have not tested yet for higher version

Comment: I've tested today for iOS 16.5.1, sadly the bug still persists. The biggest problem is that I cannot set negative value for baselineOffset.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed there has been a change in how `baselineOffset` works in iOS 16.4.

It looks like Apple fixed an old bug with `UILabel` `baselineOffset`. Earlier the baselineOffset value had to be doubled for unknown reasons. For `UITextView` `baselineOffset` worked fine without doubling.

> what should i do?

Your question is not precise but if you would like to achieve the same behavior on both versions of iOS, you can try to replace:

```swift
let baselineOffset = 20
```

to

```swift
let baselineOffset: CGFloat = {
    if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
        return 40
    } else {
        return 20
    }
}()
```

Comment: do you have any document or references that shows apple has fixed this bug?

Comment: I couldn't find any issue describing it or information in changelog. This is just my observation.

Comment: It works for positive baselineOffset, but negative values seem to be ignored in iOS 16.4 and newer when using with NSParagraphStyle's maximumLineHeight and minimumLineHeight.